# pg_resetxlog command not found

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I can't find pg_resetxlog under /usr/bin.

postgres **(PostgreSQL) 10.7** (Ubuntu 10.7-1.pgdg16.04+1)

```
cd /usr/bin
postgres@node-1:/usr/bin$ ./pg_resetxlog
-su: ./pg_resetxlog: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 10):

That's because from version 10 it has been renamed to `pg_resetwal`. And in Ubuntu and Debian the binary is located in `/usr/lib/postgresql/<version>/bin`.

The `pg_xlog` directory was renamed to `pg_wal` in version 10 and several functions, tools and options as well, to reflect that change. See [Postgres 10 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/release-10.html#id-1.11.6.12.5):

> - **Rename write-ahead log directory** **`pg_xlog`** to **`pg_wal`**, and rename transaction status directory **`pg_clog`** to **`pg_xact`** (Michael Paquier)
>
>   Users have occasionally thought that these directories contained only inessential log files, and proceeded to remove write-ahead log files or transaction status files manually, causing irrecoverable data loss. These name changes are intended to discourage such errors in future.
> - **Rename SQL functions, tools, and options that reference** **`xlog`** to **`wal`** (Robert Haas)
>
>   For example, **`pg_switch_xlog()`** becomes **`pg_switch_wal()`**, **`pg_receivexlog`** becomes **`pg_receivewal`**, and **`--xlogdir`** becomes **`--waldir`**. This is for consistency with the change of the **`pg_xlog`** directory name; in general, the **`xlog`** terminology is no longer used in any user-facing places.